# Oracle predicate issue

Tags: oracle, session

I am having some unusual issue. Whenever i run this query my database disconnects automatically or this error occurs: **ORA-12805: parallel query server died unexpectedly**.
BEGIN

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
     'CREATE TABLE ZZZ_CLAIMS_00172414_MEMID PARALLEL NOLOGGING AS
                      SELECT MEMID, ENRID, MEMFIRSTNAME, MEMLASTNAME,GENDER,DOB
                      FROM
                      (
                          SELECT /*+parallel(a,4)*/
                MEMID,
                ENRID,
                MEMFIRSTNAME,
                MEMLASTNAME,
                GENDER,
                DOB,
                LVLID2,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                          PARTITION BY
                MEMFIRSTNAME, MEMLASTNAME,GENDER,DOB ORDER BY EFFDATE DESC,TERMDATE DESC NULLS LAST) RN
                          FROM vh_eligibilities a
                WHERE LVLID2 = ''00172414''
                      )
                  WHERE RN =1
    ';      --248969
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
```

But when i remove where condition i.e WHERE LVLID2 = ''00172414'', table is created successfully. I consulted with my DBA , he suggested to alter session before creating table.

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET "_pred_move_around" = FALSE';
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
```

After altering session table is created successfully. I was using this for past two weeks then today i had to create similar table . But today table was created without using alter session query.
Then i realised i was using same query with little difference:

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
     'CREATE TABLE ZZZ_CLAIMS_00172414_MEMID PARALLEL NOLOGGING AS
                      SELECT MEMID, ENRID, MEMFIRSTNAME, MEMLASTNAME,GENDER,DOB,**LVLID2**----- The difference ------
                      FROM
                      (
                          SELECT /*+parallel(a,4)*/
                MEMID,
                ENRID,
                MEMFIRSTNAME,
                MEMLASTNAME,
                GENDER,
                DOB,
                LVLID2,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                          PARTITION BY
                MEMFIRSTNAME, MEMLASTNAME,GENDER,DOB ORDER BY EFFDATE DESC,TERMDATE DESC NULLS LAST) RN
                          FROM vh_eligibilities a
                WHERE LVLID2 = ''00172414''
                      )
                  WHERE RN =1
    ';      --248969
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
```

Can anyone tell me why i was getting this error, and after altering session table was successfully created.
And without altering session , just adding lvlid2 in select statement while creating table , table was created.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the Oracle version?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Where did you get the information to disable predicate move around?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your SQL.  This smells like it is environmental.  Consider working with your DBA and support.

Comment: @Nitish : the oracle version is oracle 12c.

Comment: @BobC : I am so confused with this issue, I got the information to disable predicate move around from DBA team. They told me its a predicate issue.

Comment: @unleashed: I too thought this was internal error. Just wanted to check any one else encountered this kind of error or not.
Thank You all

Comment: @SujanShrestha   There should be a stack trace generated for this error. This may be where your DBA found the workaround. But that is the point - it's just a band aid - you need to find the bug number and see if there is a patch. If there is no bug, then one needs to be filed.